# Performance issue in case of SQL Match Against query for Multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, database-performance

I am facing performance issue, while running a SQL query that uses MyISAM database.

To brief this, I have 3 tables:
Table: A (Engine MyISAM. Total Records: 1847) 
Table: B (Engine MyISAM. Total Records: 1110) 
Table: C (Engine MyISAM. Total Records: 57867)

Now the query I am running is taking 623 seconds to get execute and sometime it happens that connection from server(same is the case with localhost) gets aborted.

Below is the query I am executing:

```
SELECT MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist') AS 'Score',
    A.code AS 'Code',
    B.cluster AS 'Cluster',
    B.pathway AS 'Pathway',
    A.title AS 'Role',
    A.description AS 'Description'
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.code = A.code
INNER JOIN C ON B.code = C.code
WHERE MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
  OR MATCH(B.cluster, B.pathway, B.descripton) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
  OR MATCH(C.title) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
ORDER BY Score DESC, B.cluster ASC
```

You can also refer to [Pastie](http://pastie.org/4289675) (if you feel trouble seeing this SQL). I have added FULLTEXT property wherever it is applicable.

NOTE: Table A, B and C have few duplicate records as well.

Please let me know, how I can optimize this SQLfor fast output.

Comment: @Neville: What exactly you want me to attach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make sure that you have a FULLTEXT index in place on the exact set of columns you are querying from each table:

```
alter table A add fulltext index a_fti (title,description);
alter table B add fulltext index b_fti (cluster, pathway, descripton);
alter table C add fulltext index c_fti (title);
```

Then I would recommend rewriting your query to use UNION instead of OR. I've gotten much better performance from FULLTEXT searches in particular in MySQL using this approach.

Here's an example using your query:

```
select Score, Code, Cluster, Pathway, Role, Description
from
(
SELECT MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist') AS 'Score',
    A.code AS 'Code',
    B.cluster AS 'Cluster',
    B.pathway AS 'Pathway',
    A.title AS 'Role',
    A.description AS 'Description'
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.code = A.code
INNER JOIN C ON B.code = C.code
WHERE MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
UNION
SELECT MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist') AS 'Score',
    A.code AS 'Code',
    B.cluster AS 'Cluster',
    B.pathway AS 'Pathway',
    A.title AS 'Role',
    A.description AS 'Description'
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.code = A.code
INNER JOIN C ON B.code = C.code
WHERE MATCH(B.cluster, B.pathway, B.descripton) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
UNION
SELECT MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist') AS 'Score',
    A.code AS 'Code',
    B.cluster AS 'Cluster',
    B.pathway AS 'Pathway',
    A.title AS 'Role',
    A.description AS 'Description'
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.code = A.code
INNER JOIN C ON B.code = C.code
WHERE MATCH(C.title) AGAINST('Computer Graphic Artist')
) as sub_query
ORDER BY Score DESC, Cluster ASC
```

Comment: Thanks @IkeWalker for the response.. I followed your first step. For second where you have suggested me to use UNION, I will give this a try (only then I would be in a state to tell you if I figured out better o/p in terms of performance).. But would like to know (after seeing the modified query), its much bigger than the original, how will UNION makes it different from OR condition (if we talk about this particular case).. Your response would be very helpful for me to know this in depth.

Comment: Hi @Ike: I tried with the approach you suggested me above and now I have seen the improvement in Performance :-) Now the query is taking 54 seconds to fetch the result. However, I would like to know, if we can optimize it more here!! Another thing: Since this is running on development environment, hence I can expect more quicker o/p once this query executed on Production or Live server. Looking for your valuable response. Thanks a lot for helping :-)